# Can't make roughike bottom bar navigation title centered

Tags: android, xml, font-awesome, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I'm using roughike to implement bottom bar navigation in my android project. I'm not using any icon image as I felt using image & maintain resolution ratio is more complicated than using fontawesome icons. So I've written the code this way:

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/menu_bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:bb_titleTypeFace="fonts/fontawesome.ttf"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />
```

Tabs is define in `bottombar_tabs.xml` file:

```
<tabs>
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_home"
        title="\uf278" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_chat"
        title="\uf0e6" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_globe"
        title="\uf0ac" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_friends"
        title="\uf0c0" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_profile"
        title="\uf2be" />
</tabs>
```

navigation functions working properly as expected but all tabs title showing in the top of navigation. How do I make it vertically centered? I tried using gravity,layout_gravity but nothing worked.
Appriciate your help, Thanks,
Robin

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do is to change container `gravity` (container is what hosts tab `Views` like `ImageView`, `TextView` etc)

```
for (int i = 0; i < mBottomBar.getTabCount(); i++) {
      mBottomBar.getTabAtPosition(i).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
  }
```